# Is it possible to have same size characters in Text Mesh Pro?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, text

**Is it possible to have all characters in a Text Mesh Pro take up the same space**

By default the letter 'i' will take up much less space (in pixels) than letter 'w'.

Is it possible for all characters to take up the same amount of space so that a row of `iiiii` would be just as long as a row of `wwwww`?

Using the `<pos>` tag and `\t` doesn't seem to help.

How do I solve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

[Docs](http://digitalnativestudios.com/textmeshpro/docs/rich-text/#mspace):

> You can override a font's character spacing and turn it into a
> monospace font with the mspace tag. This will force all characters to
> claim the same horizontal space. You can use pixels or font units to
> set the monospace character width.

```
<mspace=mspace=200>WWWiii</mspace>
```

[image]

Comment: Even tho my solution kind of worked, your solution is just flat out better and combined with Center|Midline alignment is exactly what I needed. Truly a god walking among mere mortals. What a legend.

Comment: @aaaaaaaaaaa Definitely a great answer. If it is the best answer to your question, could you please mark their answer as the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to close off `<pos>` tag with `</pos>` tag after each character.